# What is the difference between a single version of the truth and a single source of the truth when dealing with data?

Tags: data

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_version_of_the_truth) a single version of the truth is described as "*is a technical concept describing the data warehousing ideal of having either a single centralised database, or at least a distributed synchronised database, which stores all of an organisation's data in a consistent and non-redundant form*"

A single source of the truth is described as "*refers to a data storage principle to always source a particular piece of information from one place*"

- What is the difference between a single centralized database and to source information from one place?
- What does it mean to store data is a "consistent" and "non-redundant form"?
- How does relate to scenarios when data is stored in multiple sources which are then coalesced?
- In contrast how do you describe when you are attempting to have consistent definitions e.g. The definition of a customer in one source is the same in another source?

Comment: Did you try searching for "database consistency" or "distributed system consistency"?

Comment: @Doval - Yes however that doesn't answer the question about the differences. For example, does it mean that if there is a single source of truth, it doesn't store data that is consistent and non-redundant?